# How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan in Oracle IDEs?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan, toad

In Oracle IDEs, such as Navigator, Toad, Oracle SqlDeveloper how can I get a query execution plan for a query / stored procedure?

I can find some commands for them online, even though I am not able to use them sometimes, but is there any functionality/tools built-in for these IDE's for that purpose?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-to-generate-a-useful-sql-execution-plan

Comment: In PL/SQL Developer it's under Tools, or you could add your own tab to the session browser.

Comment: Almost every IDE allows this via right mouse button at least. But this tools have different hotkeys, so this question have no one correct answer (if, for example, someone didn't ever use SQL Navigator, they cannot tell you even they are an expert in SQL Developer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's for TOAD and SQL Developer; don't know about other tools as I don't use them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ones I have found.

For navigator:

[image: At the right-left corner]

Or from Tools-Explain Plan Tolls

[image]

And I found out another tool for getting SQL Plan too. It has been of great help to me. It's

> Dell™ SQL Optimizer for Oracle®

There, you can simply write your query, and it will both find better versions of it and show and compare their plans too.

[image]